# Error while running shell script, Please check the error generated below

Tags: shell-scripting

Can someone help me what's wrong with below script.

```
START=$(date +%s)
Sta="2 4 8 10 20 40 60 80 100 150 200 250 300 300 400 450 500"
for staNodes in $Sta
do
./waf --run "scratch/freeze-count --staNodes=${staNodes} --simulationTime=10 --DataMode="OfdmRate6Mbps" --distance=1.0 --channelWidth=20 --payloadSize=1472" >& freeze-count-${staNodes}.log
done
END=$(date +%s)
echo "Elapsed time --"
echo $((END-START)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'
```

**Error:**

```
./freeze_script.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/freeze_script.sh: line 4: `do
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the DataMode argument? `\"OfdmRate6Mbps\"`

Comment: It is solved, error occurred because of spacing issue in notepad++. Thank you.